Recent Files Suddenly Dissappeared - But Are Still There
I have just had a bizarre issue where my files suddenly disappeared whilst creating a folder within Blender to save into the folder containing the vanishing files. (I am about to do a render pass).
The thing is the files are still there, and I can access them via blender, I just can't see them in Nautilus or from a Mac or Windows over the network. They show the same files, but not the recent ones. They seem to be hidden somehow. I didn't do anything special, just opened a file window to save into that folder.
Also, within that folder I am unable to rename a recently created folder. I can create the folder using Blender but not using Nautilus.
The existing files go back to Sunday. Applications that access files within that folder are still able to access them.
So what is going on? How do I get the files back/visible within Nautilus?
NB I have run a basic filesystem repair using "Disks". It took no time and so I don't know if there is anything more wrong with the drive. My Backups seem fine.

they may be hidden files - files with a "." in front of the name or in a hidden folder such as .myfolder. In Nautilus, use Ctrl+H to hide and unhide them or use the men option in Nautilus itself

I should have indicated that I had already checked that. I actually had the hidden files visible. I am wondering if I may have inadvertently deleted some and that has affected the file system. I don't understand it. The files are there - but they are not visible or accessible.
